# How to merge JSON arrays into a single array

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My postgresql database. I need to get rid of JSON nesting via sqlalchemy.

Data in the groups column groups

| groups |
| --- |
| [{"id": 5, "name": "imba"}] |
| [{"id": 1, "name": "group1"}, {"id": 3, "name": "group3"}] |

How do I create a query in SQLAlchemy?

Expected result

```
[{"id": 5, "name": "imba"}, {"id": 1, "name": "group1"}, {"id": 3, "name": "group3"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a table in Postgresql like this

```
test# table t73051318;
 id_ │                           groups                           
═════╪════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
   1 │ [{"id": 5, "name": "imba"}]
   2 │ [{"id": 1, "name": "group1"}, {"id": 3, "name": "group3"}]
(2 rows)
```

we can merge the JSONB values by calling the `json_agg` function on the result of calling `jsonb_array_elements` on the `groups` column.

```
test# select json_agg(row) as aggregated
        from (select jsonb_array_elements(groups) as row
                from t73051318
        ) q;
                                      aggregated                                       
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 [{"id": 5, "name": "imba"}, {"id": 1, "name": "group1"}, {"id": 3, "name": "group3"}]
(1 row)
```

In SQLAlchemy core, the code would look like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# Create a subquery for the jsonb_array_elements call.
subq = sa.select(
    sa.func.jsonb_array_elements(tbl.c.groups).label('row')
).subquery()

# Aggregate the subquery result.
stmt = sa.select(sa.func.json_agg(subq.c.row).label('aggregated'))

with engine.connect() as conn:
    res = conn.execute(stmt)
    print(next(res).aggregated)
```

In Flask-SQLAlchemy, the code would be

```py
# Create a subquery for the jsonb_array_elements call.
subq = db.session.query(
    db.func.jsonb_array_elements(MyModel.groups).label('row')
).subquery()

# Aggregate the subquery result.
stmt = db.session.query(db.func.json_agg(subq.c.row).label('aggregated'))

result = stmt.first()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the structure works as expected. The only thing that can cause problems is the `jsonb_array_elements` function. Here you need to be careful and use it only if your column type is JSONB. In my case, the column is of the JSON type, so I applied the `json_array_elements` function and everything worked as expected. 

With your answer, I have expanded the areas in SQL and sqlalchemy, thank you.